# Using PDO to search database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to create a search function for my website using PDO. At the moment I send the search query through the URL and then try to fetch the results however whenever I do a var dump it returns null. I tested the query on PHP my admin and it returns around 4 results.

I use a class I created to connect to the database, this works on all my other queries.

Here is my search function

```
function search($query) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Sweets` WHERE `Description` LIKE :search";
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':search', $query);

    $stmt->execute();

    $done = $stmt->fetch();

    var_dump($done[0]);


}
```

Below is the search php my form calls as an action

```
<?php
// Start our connecting to our database
require('class-database-functions.php');

$database = new Database_Functions();

// Get the search value passed through $_GET
$search_query = $_GET['query'];

$search = $database->search($search_query);


?>
```

Comment: try  $done = $stmt->fetchAll();

Comment: Did you check if `$query` in your function is correct?

Comment: Don't assume that the query is successful! Check if there are any errors. Set PDO to exception errmode and then use exceptions `try { ... } catch(PDOException $e) { ... }`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois [you should never catch errors to report them.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors). Proper PHP error reporting have to be set instead.

Comment: Is `$query` what you expect it to be? Try turning on mysql logging while you're running the query to verify that the query being sent is what you expect.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is stored in $query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Sweets` WHERE `Description` LIKE ?";
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%$query%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```